# How do I reset the "Close this dialogue box when download completes" checkbox in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

How do I reset (to the default setting - unchecked), the `Close this dialogue box when download completes` checkbox in Internet Explorer?

The problem is that the internet connection we have is so fast that the file download dialogue disappears in a flash. I've hunted around and found a large test file to download so I can uncheck this option but there must be a better way?

Is there a configuration option for this hidden somewhere in IE? I've hunted around in the Advanced and Security tabs but can't see where this can be turned off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto `Tools` -> `Intenet options` -> `Advanced` -> `Browsing` and ensure checkbox `Notify when downloads are complete` is checked

[image]

Comment: Can't see the wood for the trees :)

Answer (score 3):

I think under Tools --> Advanced Tab, under the "Browsing" section, there is a checkbox that says "Notify when download completes".  If you check that, that might keep the dialog box open for when the download completes.  Not sure since I barely ever use IE. Note: I have IE8

Comment: Haha nevermind, someone beat me too it :)